# Задача «Минимальный простой делитель»

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа, факторизация

Только начал изучать Python на платформе Сириус. Смог решить все остальные задачи из темы «while», кроме одной задачи, которая мне не позволяет пройти на следующие темы. Задача «Минимальный простой делитель числа».

**Условие:** Дано целое число, не меньшее 2. Выведите его наименьший простой делитель. Нельзя использовать дополнительные библиотеки (math и т.п.)!

**Входные данные:** Вводится целое положительное число N <= 2*10 в 9-ой степени.

**Выходные данные:** Выведите ответ на задачу.

Пытался решить, написав код с while, но мой ответ не засчитывается, по причине слишком долгого времени работы программы. Рекомендуют организовать цикл, перебирающий делители до корня из числа N: `while i*i <= N:`, но я не могу понять, как это сделать.

Мой код Python (выдаёт ошибку «Программа выполнялась слишком долго и была прервана» либо «Программа выдаёт ошибку в процессе выполнения»):

```
N = int(input())
i = 2

while i*i <= N:
    if N%i != 0:
        i += 1
print(i)
```

Не могу понять, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Ну как минимум отдельно пробуешь 2, 3 и 5, а потом только нечётные кроме делящихся на 5. Уже в 2.5 раза быстрее получится.

Comment: Надо завершать цикл как только нашли число. А сейчас как только вы нашли ответ вы перестаете увеличивать число i, а следовательно цикл становиться бесконечным ! И умножение i*i в проверке цикла это медленно. очень может статься что заранее вычисленное M=N/2 и while i <= M будет даже лучше, чем следование до корня, вычислением квадрата

Comment: n = int(input()) if n%2==0: i = 2 elif n%3==0: i = 3 elif n%4==0: i = 4 elif n%5==0: i = 5 else: i = n print(i) У меня тоже пишет, что неверный ответ. Не понимаю... Помогите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

```
def prime_f(n):
    if n%2 == 0: return 2
    i = 3
    while n%i != 0 and i*i <= n:
        i+= 2
    if i*i <= n: return i
    return n

N = int(input())

print(prime_f(N))
```

Проверяем 2 отдельно, потом только нечетные, и до корня из N - иначе N само по себе простое.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, зачем "i*i <= N"?
Если после while сразу прописать неравенство остатка нулю, то все норм работает)

```
N = int(input())
i = 2
while N%i != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Comment: А где проверка делителя на простоту?

Comment: @MiniMax Она не нужна - как вы представляете, что число делится на составное, но не делится на простое, есляющееся делителем составного? А вот к эффективности O(N) да еще и с полным перебором и правда вопросы...

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input())
s=1/2
a=N
b=int(N**s)
for i in range(2,b+1) :
        if N%i == 0:
                if a > i :
                        a=i
print(a)
```

Программа прошла проверку по времени на сириусе.

Comment: Один в один мое решение, просто замедленное в 2 раза :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Python:

a = int(input())
b = a - 1
while a < 2:
    print('Number need to be more than "2"')
    a = int(input())
while a % b != 0:
    b = b - 1
if a % b == 0:
    b = a // b
    print(b)
```

Comment: Вы тестировали свое решение на больших `N`? например на `N=2000000000`, как в условии задачи?

Comment: Точно! недосмотрел. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой вариант, по времени проходит

```
import math

num = int(input())

i = 2

while(i <= math.sqrt(num)):
  if num % i == 0:
    print(i)
    break
  i += 1
else:
  print(num)
```

Comment: А в этой ветке ещё не было таких решений?

Comment: "Нельзя использовать дополнительные библиотеки (math и т.п.)!".

Answer (score 0):

Единственный код из моих вариантов, который прошёл проверку по времени:

```
a = int(input())
b = 2
c = int(a**(1/2))

while a % b != 0 and b < c:
    b += 1

if a % b == 0:
    print(b)
else:
    print(a)
```